# Time attribute in code with custom coding

Tags: magento-1.8, attributes, backend, eav, setup

I created new attribute for products with time input in setup of my module, Setup code is here:

```
class Parseh_Course_Model_Resource_Setup extends Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Setup {   
     public function getDefaultEntities()   {
            return array(
              'catalog_product' => array(
                'entity_model'                   => 'catalog/product',
                'attribute_model'                => 'catalog/resource_eav_attribute',
                'table'                          => 'catalog/product',
                'additional_attribute_table'     => 'catalog/eav_attribute',
                'entity_attribute_collection'    => 'catalog/product_attribute_collection',
                'attributes'                     => array(
                  'course_end_time' => array(
                    'type'                       => 'varchar',
                    'label'                      => 'End Time',
                    'input'                      => 'time',
                    'backend'                    => 'parseh_course/course_attribute_backend_time',
                    'required'                   => true,
                    'user_defined'               => false,
                    'sort_order'                 => 4,
                    'global'                     => Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_STORE,
                    'used_in_product_listing'    => true,
                    'visible_on_front'           => true,
                    'apply_to'                   => Parseh_Course_Model_Product_Type::TYPE_COURSE,
                    'group'                      => 'Scheduling',
                  ),

                )
              )
            );   
      } 
}
```

As you see I used "parseh_course/course_attribute_backend_time" model for this input backend.

```
class Parseh_Course_Model_Course_Attribute_Backend_Time extends Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Attribute_Backend_Abstract
{
  public function beforeSave($object) {
    $attributeCode = $this->getAttribute()->getName();
    $data = $object->getData($attributeCode);
    if (!is_array($data)) {
      $data = array();
    }
    $object->setData($attributeCode, join(':', $data));
    if (is_null($object->getData($attributeCode))) {
      $object->setData($attributeCode, false);
    }
  }

  public function afterLoad($object) {
    $attributeCode = $this->getAttribute()->getName();
    $data = $object->getData($attributeCode);
    if ($data) {
      $object->setData($attributeCode, explode(':', $data));
    }

    return $this;
  }
}
```

In beforeSave function I join hour, minute and seconds with ":" and make a string to save in database.
In afterLoad function the value of attribute loads correct same as "10:30:00" but when I explode it and create an array of data to fill time inputs in edit form of product, values of hour, minute, second inputs are 00.

Please help me!

Comment: what happens if you simply log the results of the explode?

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:
Instead of

```
$object->setData($attributeCode, explode(':', $data));
```

use this:

```
$object->setData($attributeCode, implode(',',explode(':', $data)));
```

this will transform the value from `10:30:00` to `10,30,00`.
And here is why this should work.
In the class `Varien_Data_Form_Element_Time`, the one that renders the time type element there is this code in the method `getElementHtml`.

```
    if( $value = $this->getValue() ) {
        $values = explode(',', $value);
        if( is_array($values) && count($values) == 3 ) {
            $value_hrs = $values[0];
            $value_min = $values[1];
            $value_sec = $values[2];
        }
    }
```

So Magento expects a string value with the values for hour, minute and second separated by comma. (See second line in the code above)